# Combine Topbar and Sidebar into single "Nav" layout - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a react app that renders 2 layouts, a layout without the sidebar nav and topbar when you are not logged in, and then a different layout that does render the topbar and sidebar nav when you are logged in (through a context).

The issue that I am facing is that when logged in, the topbar and sidebar nav render as separate components and any other component that I wish to display ends up all the way at the bottom - see these images for context [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr9vJ.png)  [Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scCRq.png)

As you can see, everything renders top down ("Dashboard" is an example of a component that I would like rendered next to and below the sidebar and topbar. What I would like to do is render the topbar and sidebar as a single component, and then render any other page components in that large white space. Perhaps there is a way to combine the two bars into a single layout?

I will share some code below...

Topbar.jsx

```
import "startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-master/css/sb-admin-2.min.css";
import { useAuth } from "../../hooks/auth";

export const TopBar = () => {
  const user = useAuth().user;

  const { logout } = useAuth();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    logout();
  };

  return (
    <div id="content-wrapper" className="d-flex flex-column">
      <div id="content">
        <div className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">
          <button
            id="sidebarToggleTop"
            className="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3"
          >
            <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <form className="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                placeholder="Search for..."
                aria-label="Search"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
              />
              <div className="input-group-append">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li className="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
              <div
                className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                id="alertsDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i>

                <span className="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <div className="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block" />
            <li className="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <div
                className="nav-link"
                id="userDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <text className="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">
                  Hi, {user}!
                </text>
                <i className="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <div
                className="nav-link"
                id="userDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <button
                  className="btn btn-secondary btn-circle"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Navbar.jsx (sidebar)

```
import "startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-master/css/sb-admin-2.min.css";
import { useAuth } from "../../hooks/auth";

export const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <ul
        className="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion"
        id="accordionSidebar"
      >
        <hr className="sidebar-divider my-0" />

        <li className="nav-item active">
          <a className="nav-link" href="index.html">
            <i className="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <hr className="sidebar-divider" />

        <div className="sidebar-heading">Interface</div>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            className="nav-link collapsed"
            href="#"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseTwo"
          >
            <i className="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
            <span>Components</span>
          </a>
          <div
            id="collapseTwo"
            className="collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
            data-parent="#accordionSidebar"
          >
            <div className="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
              <h6 className="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">
                Buttons
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="cards.html">
                Cards
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            className="nav-link collapsed"
            href="#"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapseUtilities"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseUtilities"
          >
            <i className="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
            <span>Utilities</span>
          </a>
          <div
            id="collapseUtilities"
            className="collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingUtilities"
            data-parent="#accordionSidebar"
          >
            <div className="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
              <h6 className="collapse-header">Custom Utilities:</h6>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="utilities-color.html">
                Colors
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="utilities-border.html">
                Borders
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="utilities-animation.html">
                Animations
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="utilities-other.html">
                Other
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <hr className="sidebar-divider" />

        <div className="sidebar-heading">Addons</div>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            className="nav-link collapsed"
            href="#"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapsePages"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapsePages"
          >
            <i className="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
            <span>Pages</span>
          </a>
          <div
            id="collapsePages"
            className="collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingPages"
            data-parent="#accordionSidebar"
          >
            <div className="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
              <h6 className="collapse-header">Login Screens:</h6>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="login.html">
                Login
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="register.html">
                Register
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="forgot-password.html">
                Forgot Password
              </a>
              <div className="collapse-divider"></div>
              <h6 className="collapse-header">Other Pages:</h6>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="404.html">
                404 Page
              </a>
              <a className="collapse-item" href="blank.html">
                Blank Page
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="charts.html">
            <i className="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
            <span>Charts</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="tables.html">
            <i className="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
            <span>Tables</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <hr className="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block" />

        <div className="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
          <button className="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle" />
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

ProtectedLayout.jsx (layout rendered when logged in)

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router";
import { Navbar } from "../components/common/Navbar";
import { TopBar } from "../components/common/Topbar";

export const ProtectedLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <TopBar />
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

App.js (routing)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoginLayout } from "./layout/LoginLayout";
import { ProtectedLayout } from "./layout/ProtectedLayout";
import { ProtectRoutes } from "./hooks/protectedRoute";
import { Login } from "./pages/LoginPage";
import { Dashboard } from "./pages/DashboardPage";
import { Hi } from "./pages/HiPage";
import { About } from "./pages/AboutPage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<LoginLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/auth" element={<ProtectRoutes />}>
        <Route
          path="/auth/dashboard"
          element={
            <>
              <ProtectedLayout />
              <Dashboard />
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/auth/hi"
          element={
            <>
              <ProtectedLayout />
              <Hi />
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/auth/about"
          element={
            <>
              <ProtectedLayout />
              <About />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Also, if you have any suggestions on bettering the routing I would be incredibly grateful.

Please let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: This is basically a CSS question where you want to render the navbar at the top of the screen and then the sidebar *and* content below it in effectively two columns. Have you tried a grid layout or similar?

Comment: Works - thank you @DrewReese. I'm using a template for the frontend just to speed up the styling process, turns out the template uses flex so I'll just have to refactor to get the grid in place. Let me know if I can buy you a coffee lol, feel like I asked a dumb question

Comment: Ah, lol, no worries. Hopefully you learned something and/or increased your skillset even just a smidge. You can repay me by paying it forward where you can. Cheers.

Comment: Most definitely will, @DrewReese. I basically live on stack overflow and I see a lot of your responses on questions I read through - props for being so helpful in the community!

Comment: Hi @DrewReese! I hope things are going well. I have a quick question unrelated to this post that I think you would know that answer to. Regarding useState, when a user navigates to another page, does that state clear? I have many tables throughout my web app that each contain dozens of rows. I'm wondering if they'll all be "cached" to local memory as the user navigates around. Don't want the app to slow down the user's computer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: React component state persists for the life of the component. When the component unmounts, its state should be released/garbage collected.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese! I hope things are going well. I have a similar question but it's related to Next.js. I'm a newbie in Next.js, though I have good knowledge of React. I also want to have two layouts, one with the Topbar when the user is not logged in and a second layout with both the Topbar and the Sidebar when logged in. As Next.js uses page-based routing, how can we combine both of them in a single layout? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NetYogi Next.js v13 really changed things. I'm not very familiar with Next.js so I'm suggestion to you would be to create a new post for your specific issue. Feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take look when available. RRD is client-side routing though, so it's unclear if it would even be helpful for you with server-side rendering from Next.js.